# Issue with if / else statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement, gcc

I'm having a little trouble with my if / else structure.

So, for `" num = 65279"`, I'm not really sure why, this if / else structure I wrote ends up going into the first if, as expected, but also goes into the last `if ("if(num <= 65535")`. I'm not sure why this is happening, since I used the { } correctly. How can I better restructure my code so that this error doesn't happen any more. Or what am I doing for that error to happen? num is an unsigned short.

I'm using Linux gcc compiler.

```
if(num >= 55296 && num < 56320){ 
        ...
}
else{   
    if(num <= 127){
                ...
    }
    else{
        if(num <= 2047){
                ...
        }
        else{
            if(num <= 65535){   ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger...

Comment: num is a short, 2 bytes

Comment: `short`? In that case it cannot have any of the values 65279, 55296, 56320, or 65535. Its range is -32768 to +32767.

Comment: @WeatherVane *`short`? In that case it cannot have any of the values 65279, 55296, 56320, or 65535. Its range is -32768 to +32767.* Probably being overly pedantic here because the implementation in question probably is limited to +/-32K, but that's the minimum allowable range for `short`.  Per **5.2.4.2.1  Sizes of integer types
<limits.h>** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):  "implementation-defined values shall be **equal or greater in magnitude** (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign."  So a `short` *could* have the values listed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that could be a valid point, but the comment still says "short, 2 bytes". The question has been edited to `unsigned short`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I'm using an unsigned short. All the values i'm using work inside an unsigned short just perfect.

Comment: I tried this code with num = 65279 and it did *not* go into the first `if` condition, as expected.  Your problem is in some other piece of code you're not showing us.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can run to reproduce your issue which exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should format your code properly, it makes it a lot easier to understand. Here you can see all of the points the program will reach, (the ...'s). The two if statements you mentioned can both run according to your code. If this isn't how it should be then you need to rewrite it. If they should both be able to run then you need to specify what the value of num is and give more information.

```
if(num >= 55296 && num < 56320) { 
    ...
} else {   
    if(num <= 127) {
        ...
    } else {
        if(num <= 2047) {
            ...
        } else {
            if(num <= 65535) {
                ...
            } else {//I added this
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I see that you said num is a 2 byte integer, so the part I added would never actually run. "if(num <= 65535) {" will always be true because you can't store any number higher.

Comment: What I was trying to do was: I wan't the first " If " to be considered. If it's true, then do what's inside it. If it's not true, don't even consider looking inside the "else" statement. Just jump it and go along with the code.

Comment: @NodaDeCaju That is the complete opposite purpose of an else statement. It sounds like you want to code in the if statement, but if that's the case then (num <= 127) and (num <= 2047) would always be false, and (num <= 65535) would always be true. What is it you're trying to do with this code?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the first comment wrong. What I want is to check the first 'if', if it's true, then do what's inside it and don't even consider looking to the else statement. If it's not true, then, and only then, look at the else statement.

Comment: That's what your code is doing. Also the statement "if(num <= 65535) {" is redundant because it will always be true for a 2 byte integer.

Comment: I know `if(num <= 65535)` is always true. But I don't want my program to even consider it if the first `if` of them all is true.

Answer (score 0):

If the num value is equal to `65279`, as you say, then your code is simply doing what you told it to. There is no error. Your last condition says to execute if the num value is `less than 65535`. Which, `65279 IS less than 65535`. I'm not sure you articulated this question very well, but this seems to be the answer.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is the following: if the first " if " is true, then do what's inside it and don't even consider looking at " else " possibilities and just go on with the code. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, you need to give a better example of what you are DOING and what you are EXPECTING and what you are GETTING. It makes it much easier to assist you. Side note: You aren't happen to be running this inside a loop, are you?

Comment: I'm in fact running it inside a loop, but never using the same value of 'num' for the same loop. I mean, after every loop, the value of 'num' changes. What I want is for the program to check the first 'if' statement, if it's true, then do what's inside it, and don't even look at the else statement and go along doing other instructions inside the loop. If the first 'if' is false, then, and only then, check to see what's inside the 'else' statement.

Comment: If you want it to stop checking once they are deemed true and executed, try adding a `continue;` after the code it executes.

Comment: I added the `continue;`, but with no success. The program still checks the `else` statement, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting here won't show up in a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer.

Kudeos for using consistent indentation as clean formatting is actually very important in understanding code as you try to read it.  But you're making your code more complex than it needs to be.

This code

```
if ( cond1 )
{
    ...
}
else
{
    if ( cond2 )
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        if ( cond3 )
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            if ( cond4 )
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is the same as

```
if ( cond1 )
{
    ...
}
else if ( cond2 )
{
    ...
}
else if ( cond3 )
{
    ...
}
else if ( cond4 )
{
    ...
}
```

Which one is simpler and much easier to understand?